# Oauth2 and OpenId Connect Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

We are trying to implement an application where UI is in angular and backend is in Spring boot.
We need to implement openId and oauth2 in our application.
Backend api's needs to be more secure.

I am just confusing which  oauth flow to be used  either authorization grant flow and password grant flow.

Can any one suggest me which one need to use in this scenario and why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Storing tokens in the front end is not recommended. It also distributes token handling logic across FE and BE because BE will have to validate tokens on each request anyway.

Therefore to avoid handling and refreshing tokens in the frontend and to simplify the overall architecture, you can implement authorization code flow in Spring Boot. This will also reduce the risk of XSS exposure in the FE.

You could implement a dedicated endpoint that initiates the flow and receives code from identity server. It then exchanges this code for id token and stores it. Then it creates an HttpOnly, strict SameOrigin session cookie for the front end. From that point onwards all calls to the API inside your Spring Boot will automatically carry this cookie without any additional code on the FE.

To eliminate token storage on the BE, you could even put token inside the cookie. However, the token may be quite large and may need to be broken into chunks. This would not affect FE in any way.

You will need to check token expiry on each API call inside the BE and refresh token in the backend as well. This will keep user session seamless. If token can not be refreshed due to revocation or refresh token expiry, the API would have to return 401 and the FE would need to initiate re-login.